# flutter_reactive_ble is there a ble command queue

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm using flutter_reactive_ble 5.0.2
I wonder is there a queue that make sure that only 1 command execute at a time or should I take care of it in my development?
If for example I call:
subscribeToCharacteristic

then without waiting call to write command that will cause the notification to raise, should I count on the fact that the notification will be finished before the write command (due to a command queue )